# Google maps doesn't work on IE7

Tags: php, internet-explorer, google-maps

I have a problem with Google Maps, it works fine on IE8, IE9, Firefox etc.. But not on IE7.

Here my code :

```
$(function ()
{
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng($('.lat').text(), $('.lng').text());


    var myOptions = {         

  zoom: parseInt($('.zoom').text()),        
  center: latlng,         
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP     
 };    

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);    

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({        
  position: latlng,        
  map: map,        
  title: $('.titre').text()     
 });
});
```

On Ie7, i have just an empty rectangle...

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: Ie 7 isn't supported by google apps any longer.  
http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2011/06/our-plans-to-support-modern-browsers.html
You might be able to get it to work, but some features might be broken.

Comment: Hum yeah, there isn't a solution ?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but since I don't see an obvious error in the script, and it works on other versions of IE, it is a possibility.

Comment: one problem might be is you're using `.text()` to get data from your page and use them for creating your LatLng. This expects floating point numbers, not the strings that .text() gives you. Usually this shouldn't be a problem, unless IE7 does something weird with it. You might want to try hardcoding values initially and test if that works or not